# inapp purchases in android applications from different accounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'd like to embed inapp purchases in my android applications. My friend also would like to implement the same feature in his applications. Is it possible to setup purchases from two different google accounts on the dedicated one ? To be more clear - it it possible to setup inapp purchases from my friend's applications (that's placed in his google acount) to my account ?  The reason - my friend does not have merchant account on google play.

Comment: check my answer below. let me know it is useful for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

As what I have understood your question:
you want to place new application(your friend's application) in your account and also want to add your friend Google account(Testing account for the application) into Google play console.

**My Answer:**

Yes, it is possible for both cases.

1) you can add more then one application into your Google developer console. That means you can also add your friend application's signed apk file into your account by creating new application. And one more thing you have to add into console that is his Google account(Google id for testing application), you can simply add it from the settings tag.

2) you can also add more then one Google account(Google id for testing the application) for the single application by using commas. That means one application can be test by the two different accounts.

Let me know if I  am not understood your question properly or may you want to explain something else.

Hope it will help you.